# Is result from Hapi.js route handler available on server extension points?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I was wondering, if it is possible to get the result from a route handler on extension points like onPostHandler and onPreRequest?, and if is the case, into what properties should I look to get the result value? let's say that this is what I would like to do:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/mypath'
  handler: function(request, reply){
    reply({a : 0});
  }
});

server.ext('onPostHandler', function(request, reply){
  var newResponse = _.assignIn( // <--- extend
    request.<path-to-actual-result-from-handler>,
    {b : 1}
  );
  reply(newResponse);
});
```

You maybe are asking yourself, why don't you include property b on the handler response? because the handler is on 3rd party code that I was asked not to modify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hapi.js Proxy - change the response before reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263162/hapi-js-proxy-change-the-response-before-reply)

Comment: I suppose you eventually found out that you could use `request.response`, the body of the response being in `request.response.source`?

Comment: Indeed, what I wasnt aware is that it was an IncomingMessage object